# Python module for automated web processes?

Tags: python

I want to use python to login into an email and continually search/refresh mailbox till a particular email is found, upon which another action will be taken on another website.

After first I tried poplib before moving onto splinter and webbrowser, all of which have failed me. Any suggestions? I need a way for python to not only access a webpage but to locate elements for manipulation (e.g buttons, textboxs, etc). I thought this would be easy but I'm having a hard time here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Typically, Selenium is used for functional testing and Beautiful Soup is used for scraping. Since it sounds like interactions are required for your use case, I would go with Selenium. Here is a simple, oldie but goodie, example of login with Selenium/Python: http://wrongturnon.blogspot.com/2011/12/simple-gmail-login-automation-with.html

Good luck!

Comment: @Peter how did that work out?

Comment: great, working with Selenium at the moment, thank you